# How to say the similarity in a specific property

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote

> OXPath allows node and form field selection based on visual features by exposing all CSS properties via a new axis called style, which is absent in XPath. (In this respect / .....), CWrap also uses CSS properties ...

I want to say the CWrap also has the same feature. What are the suitable phrases for the blank in the parentheses?

Comment: .... which is absent from XPath but available with CWrap.

Comment: @TRomano is "in this respect" correct too?

Comment: You can answer that question for yourself by writing "In respect of ____" or "With respect to _____" and then filling in the blank.  If you have trouble filling in the blank, you will know that "In this respect" has problems.  The antecedent of "this respect" is unclear here, IMO.

Comment: @Ahmad In _what_ respect does CWrap also use CSS properties? (This is the long verson of TRomano's comment.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant as the question title offers, I want to say they are similar in this aspect/respect/.... which is the using of CSS properties.

Comment: You might consider: _Similarly, CWrap uses CSS properties to (do sth),_ or _Like OXPath, CWrap uses CSS properties to (do sth)._ The problem with _In this respect_ is that it needs a specific antecedent, and that antecedent isn't clear at all from the previous sentence.

Comment: @P.E.Dant How about this sentence *One weakness of OXPath is its incapability to make even trivial transformations on the extracted data. In this case, CWrap provides functions like RegEx for manipulating and storing the extracted data*. Did I use "in this case" properly? Could it be "in this respect"?